# Run JQuery Function on Page Load and Store the Result

Tags: function, load, store, document

I've got a script that hides most of the page when you first load the webpage.
When it does this, I want it to run a function which gets the current date, then saves it.

I've having trouble getting to do this for a few reasons.

Here is the page load code, where it hides the page if it's not been setup:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
            if (setup=="true") {
                    $("#show-page").show();
                    loadSetup();
            } else {
                    $("#page-nav").hide();
            }
    });
```

Here is the date function:

```
function getStartDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth();
        var yyyy = today.getYear();   

    var startDate = dd + (mm * 30) + (yyyy * 360)
//edit
//      return startDate
    $("#start-date").val(startDate);
    localStorage.startDate = $("#start-date").val();
}
```

I then want an if function in the first part of the loading page which says if the stored start date + 30 is less than the current date, show a message that gives them an updated url (isNewUrlNeeded()).

This was my attempt:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
        if (setup=="true") {
                $("#show-page").show();
                loadSetup();
                isNewUrlNeeded();
        } else {
                $("#page-nav").hide();
                getStartDate();
        }
});
```

The problem here is that the getStartDate value isn't stored and I'm not sure how to store it. The reason it needs to be stored is so I can call on it later in the function isNewUrlNeeded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Kind Regards,

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
function getStartDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth();
    var yyyy = today.getYear();   

    var startDate = dd + (mm * 30) + (yyyy * 360)
    $("#show-page").data("start-date", startDate);
}
```

To retrieve this date you could do the follow :

```
var startDate = $("#show-page").data("start-date");
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be saving the result, firebug shows it as undefined

Comment: Are you sure? I mean, this is as standard jquery API, are you sure your #show-page element exists in the dom?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using the page-show for this though, is there no way to locally store this value?

Comment: because it needs to be called again at a later stage

Comment: If you using HTML5 then you can use localstorage api for that purpose, if not, you can define a globale variable to store your data

Comment: Hi, I am using HTML5. The above method works initially, so it gets the startDate value, but after a refresh it seems to go. Localstorage should get past this issue but I'm not sure how to do it in this case. I've updated the code to include my attempt.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('start-date', startDate ) // to set date

Comment: localStorage.getItem('start-date') // to get date

Comment: Problem was I was using the $ when storing the value (I've been using localstorage to store values for gui elements, forgot that I'm not doing that now). Thanks again